# How get number from argument line?

Tags: c

I have this code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
printf("%i\n", (int) *argv[1])
}
```

when I execute compiled code with command *./a.out 6* it prints number 54, but I need exactly 6.

Comment: Arguments are passed as an array of strings. You need to [convert the string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol).

Comment: Oh, and you should *definitely* check that an argument is actually passed byfore you try to use any of the strings in the array. Add e.g. a check line `if (argc > 1) { /* have at least one argument */ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line arguments are passed as C strings, not as numbers. You cannot cast a C string to its corresponding number, because it is a pointer to a sequence of characters, not the number itself.

Your code attempts to cast the first character in a string representing `6`, i.e. `"6"`, to `int`. The cast succeeds, because `char` is an integral numeric type, but you get 54 instead of 6 because that is the character code of `'6'` on your system.

You can use [`atoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/atoi) to do the conversion properly:

```
int n = atoi(argv[1]);
printf("%i\n", n);
```

You need to include `<stdlib.h>` in order for this to compile.

Answer (score 2):

You are type casting a char * to an int. This will result in the ASCII value of it. %i and %d point to the same thing i.e signed integers.
Refer: [Format specifiers in C](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c.html)

You can use the following

```
printf("%s", argv[1]);
```

or

```
printf("%d", atoi(argv[1]));
```

Remember when using atoi(argv[1](http://codeforwin.org/2015/05/list-of-all-format-specifiers-in-c.html)), there should be no other ASCII characters such as -,+ etc. in these cases atoi() will return 0, since atoi() will not detect any errors (Refer: http://linux.die.net/man/3/atoi). So remember to strip all these characters from the argument and just pass pure numbers. Alternatively you can write your own atoi() too, if you fell like it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't cast a `char *` to `int` like this. Have a look at `atoi();`.
Next, if you want to print only decimal numbers, you should you the `%d` flag, instead of `%i`. If you want to print every arguments, you should use `%s` flag, so you don't have to cast your argument.

Last but not least, in your code, you won't print the argument, but the pointer of the value. 6 seems to point on 54, which is its ASCII value.
To print the value, you can do as below:

`printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));`

OR
`printf("%s\n", argv[1]);`